# Picture Library Slideshow how to change picture library

Tags: web-part

The picture library slideshow that I added does not automatically connect to the picture library I want and there is no drop down menu to choose another. How do I get it to change the Library?

Answer (score 0):

To change Picture Library

> Edit Web Part > below Picture Library > Select your Library as shown below

[image]

Comment: My picture slideshow web-part will not let me choose Asset Libraries, only Picture Libraries, and it will only let me select a Picture Library on the same site as the web part (libraries from sub-sites are not available). Is there any workaround for this so I can show images form an Asset Library on a sub-site?

Comment: you mentioned in your question that it is picture library ! so my answer related to your quest :) regarding Asset Library you can't use this web part because it may have videos.